# How do you implement a generic CRUD grid using knockout.js?

Tags: model-view-controller, knockout.js, asp.net-web-api

I have a very nice grid with Create, Retrieve, Edit and Delete functionality.  I am using knockout.js on the client and WebAPI on the back end.

I would like to extend this to a number of different objects.  Essentially I have a List<T> where T is an MVC view model and the knockout view and view model should be able to work out what they should look like based on T.

Does anyone know of a simple way to display any viewmodel (with specific controls for editing based on the viewmodel itself - eg datepicker for dates, input for string, drop downs etc) in a grid format and have generic CRUD functions.

Below is an example of the exiting HTML I am using (for a specific object):

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
        <th>Value Date</th>
        <th>Position Date</th>
        <th>Book</th>
        <th>Currency</th>
        <th>Currency Base</th>
        <th>Amount1</th>
        <th>Amount2</th>
        <th>Position Type</th>
        <th style="width: 100px; text-align:right;" />
        </tr>
    </thead>
   <tbody data-bind=" template:{name:templateToUse, foreach: pagedList }"></tbody>
</table>
```

and the templates look like this:

```
<script id="itemsTmpl" type="text/html">
<tr>
    <td data-bind="text: valueDate.formattedDate"></td>
    <td data-bind="text: positionDate.formattedDate"></td>
    <td data-bind="text: book"></td>
    <td data-bind="text: currency"></td>
    <td data-bind="text: currencyBase"></td>
    <td data-bind="text: amount1"></td>
    <td data-bind="text: amount2"></td>
    <td data-bind="text: positionType"></td>
    <td class="buttons">
        <a class="btn" data-bind="click: $root.edit" href="#" title="edit"><i class="icon-pencil"></i></a>
        <a class="btn" data-bind="click: $root.remove" href="#" title="remove"><i class="icon-trash"></i></a>
    </td>
</tr>
</script>

<script id="editTmpl" type="text/html">
<tr>
    <td><input data-bind="datepicker: valueDate.formattedDate, datepickerOptions: { dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd' }"/></td>
    <td><input data-bind="datepicker: positionDate.formattedDate, datepickerOptions: { dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd' }"/></td>
    <td><input data-bind="value: book"/></td>
    <td><input data-bind="value: currency"/></td>
    <td><input data-bind="value: currencyBase"/></td>
    <td><input data-bind="value: amount1"/></td>
    <td><input data-bind="value: amount2"/></td>
    <td><input data-bind="value: positionType"/></td>
    <td class="buttons">
        <a class="btn btn-success" data-bind="click: $root.save" href="#" title="save"><i class="icon-ok"></i></a>
        <a class="btn" data-bind="click: $root.cancel" href="#" title="cancel"><i class="icon-remove"></i></a>
    </td>
</tr>
</script>
```

I would like the View as well as the View Model to be generic and not "hard-coded" as above.  I am sure someone else must have done something like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution would be that:

1. AJAX call gets a list of JSON viewmodels
2. If list is empty then do not display anything
3. If list has items, pick first item and go through properties
4. Start constructing the view on the client by looping through proprties
5. Append the string as a DOM element to the main DIV
6. Wireup knockout

There are problems with this approach. What if a property is null for the first object but exists in another? If so we do not setup the element for it.

A **better option** is to use **content negotiation** to get a dedicated template:

So GET /api/customers will return customers but if you request text/knockout-template+html then you get back a knockout template as string and then you append to DIV and wireup knockout. **So server can generate template using reflection or customise for some models.**

Comment: Thanks for this - was hoping that someone has already put together something like this.  If not, I'll do it and put a link back into this question.

I prefer option 2 - will spend some time on this over the next few days if I can't find anything else

Comment: @loilo: Just bring this to your attention in case it interests you (Please refer to your former server/client side templating question) :-)